# easiest/quickest way to convert functionality provided by a php script, into an API

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have a set of PHP scripts that are directly executed-- now I want to convert the core code (ie the functionality provided by the PHP scripts into an API-- I would also want the API to use OAuth2 for authenticating a user (before the API can actually be used by the authenticated user...)

What is the shortest/easiest way to accomplish this? If there is some way of automating this, doing it very quickly that would be great because I have a lot of PHP code that I want to convert into an API.

Any links to guides/how-to s on this subject would also be welcome....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the restler framework, If you have build your code in object oriented fashion, this will be easier for you to use the restler.

Comment: ideally I am looking for something that just takes the existing functions->PHP and converts them into equivalent API functions-- this can be done in Java (there are many frameworks for creating API s out of Java code in this manner) but since I am new to PHP hence I dont know if this can be done in PHP...Do let me know  whether(and how) such function->API conversion is possible in PHP...Thanks

Comment: i just went through Restler framework docs and it looks very nice-and well suited fmr my purpose... thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I usually use Slim Framework for this: http://slimframework.com/

It has a nice set of RESTful Helpers, a Templating system (although I never used it), uses function names to map to a route (like `$app->get(/my/path/id/:id/`) and it uses lambda functions to enable the developer to add functionality (it may not be default PHP Style, but I like it)